# Symfony Debug mode loads without layout on error

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

Whenever I have an "Fatal error"  I'm expecting a nice layout in symfony's debug mode (eg:frontend_dev.php/module/action) with a stacktrace, but what I see is really a terribly unformatted page with continuous text.

If I try this without the _dev specified, meaning without debug turned on, I see a plain white page. I was expecting a symfony 500 page or something similar. I'm not too sure how to debug this or what i did to cause it.

If however, I manually throw an exception everything works as expected. I see a pretty 500 page in prod mode and a nicely formatted page for the stacktrace.

Comment: Is it possible that the unformatted error page is missing the css?

Comment: Make sure you copied (or symlinked) the lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf directory under web/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Fatal errors should not be caught](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277224/how-do-i-catch-a-php-fatal-error), this is why there won't be any formatting for them: Symfony cannot transform them as Exceptions and format them nicely. If you want something prettier, you can set html_errors to On and install XDebug.